# Remove an attribute from all the children elements of body

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using a script from bing. Well, when i run it, it assigns an attribute "lang" to all of the elements and changing my own styling. The script is online so i can't edit it. What i can do is remove that attribute from all the elements using jquery so no styling change would occur. This is what i have tried so far after searching through.

```
$('body').children("*").removeAttr('lang');

$('body').find("*").removeAttr("lang");
```

They are not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: it has to be executed after the bing script is executed

Comment: @Prannav Ram
I tried it alrady but it is also not working.

Comment: @ArunPJohny
yes i am executing it after the script. But it is not working.

Comment: as a debugging step try `setTimeout(function(){$('body').find("*").removeAttr("lang")}, 5000)`

Comment: Post a link to the Bing JavaScript file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Has Attribute Selector [name]`](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) and then use [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.

```js
$('[lang]').removeAttr('lang');

console.log($('span').prop('outerHTML'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span lang='en'>1</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
$('*').removeAttr('lang');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$($("body [lang]").removeAttr("lang"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after the script:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').find('*').removeAttr("lang");
}, 0);
```